# What is 'connectservice.app'

Tags: macos

It's in my Login Items.  Examining the package shows a reference to arcsoft.com.  But I don't have either of their Mac products (Panorama Maker or PhotoStudio) installed, and never have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I't main purpose is to keep you using [ArcSoft products](http://www.arcsoft.com/product/mac.html).

1. Stop ArcSoft Connect Service:
   Launch "Activity Monitor" from `/Applications/Utilities`, select "ConnectService" and then click Quit Process.
2. Delete following folders or files:

   `/Applications/ArcSoft Connect Suite`

   `/Applications/[Product Name]`

   `/Library/Application Support/ArcSoft`

   `/Library/Receipts/*.pkg`

   `~/Library/Preferences/com.arcsoft.*`

   `~/Library/Preferences/Application Support/ArcSoft`

   `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.arcsoft.*`

Notes: 
`[Product Name]`: represents the [ArcSoft product](http://www.arcsoft.com/product/mac.html) you want to uninstall (there may be some more than listed there).

You may also need to read [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2257953?start=0&tstart=0).